# Javascript equation tag doesn't update text on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having some trouble with some code of mine. I'm sure its a simple error, but i'm very new to html, js and jquery. I'm having some trouble with an equation which doesn't seem to be working. it could also be an issue with the text not updating with the variable.

```js
var total = 0
var othernumber = 0

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id2").click(function() {
    if (total >= 10) {
      othernumber++;
      total - 10;
      $("#othernumber").text(othernumber);
      $("#total").text(total);
    };
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id").click(function() {
    total++;
    $("#total").text(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="total">0</h1>
  <h3 id="othernumber">0</h3>
  <button id="id">add one</button>
  <button id="id2">add one when total >= 10 and then subtract ten</button>
</body>
```

I'm specifically having problems with this snippet of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#id2").click(function() {
            if (total >= 10) {
              othernumber++;
              total - 10;
              $("#othernumber").text(othernumber);
              $("#total").text(total);
            };
          });
        });
```

it doesn't seem to want to subtract 10 from total, or maybe it just isnt updating the text. thanks in advance!

Comment: `#id2` only adds 1 when the total is already greater than 10.

Comment: The statement below needs to be updated
"total - 10"
should be 
"total = total - 10;"

Comment: ...or `total -= 10;`

Answer (score 3):

You are subtracting 10 from total, but you aren't saving it to a variable.
It should be:

```
total = total - 10;
```